# Nullable reference types in swashbuckle cli and nswag in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, nswag

I'm using dotnet swagger cli to make a swagger definition file for an ASP.NET 5.0 web api, and using nswag to generate C# client classes, but I've run into a snag. I want all my reference types to be nullable, unless they're marked with Required. For my primitive fields it just follows C# convetions whether it's nullable or not, but my references don't get marked with nullable:true in the swagger definition.

I've tried serializing as V2 instead, but then it just makes everything nullable, which I also don't want.

I'm using the following CLI command right now:

```
dotnet swagger tofile --serializeasv2 --output $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\nswag\swagger.json project.dll v1" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" WorkingDirectory="$(OutputPath)"
```

Comment: Could you give an example of swagger cli command you've used?

Comment: > I want all my reference types to be nullable, unless they're marked with Required.

May I ask why?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know how to implement exactly the behavior you've mentioned.
Would it suffice to have nullable properties in API project staying the same(nullable) in generated code?

To do so, you can add this into you API project

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
```

and then enable the following option in NSwag generator:  `generateNullableReferenceTypes=true`.

This option looks like "Generate Nullable Reference Type..." in "DTO Classes" section in NswagStudio UI.

I think this approach should also work with swagger cli

Comment: Thanks, that is what I've been looking for so far.